# Mongo Queries in Java

Tags: java, jquery, mongodb, criteria

I work with Mongo and Java. Actually I use `Criteria` to make `select` . 
for example

```
Criteria.where("customerType").is(customerType) (1)
```

for me `customerType` is key in MongoDB. If I change it in future, my (1) query will be

useless and more bad if I used it many times my code will be broken. I have googled ,but

there is no result. My question is , are there any project or workaround for such problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've got your question completely, but take a look at spring-data-mongo http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/

You would just need to declare interface

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {

    public Customer findByCustomerType(String customerType);

}
```

and spring will do it's magic, providing implementation under the hood.